# How to automatically scale down a 100% div without showing browser vertical scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with three rows. I have 1 main #container div (height 100%) and inside it is a table with 3 rows. The first and last row have fixed size content. In the second row is a #content div with 100% height and overflow:auto. (actually the table has a lot more rows and the page has more divs, but for the sake of clarity i scalled it down for this question).

If there is more content in #content than fits, a vertical scrollbar should appear next to that div's content. However, a vertical scrollbar appears at the browser window itself. When i set the #content div to a fixed size however, that vertical scrollbar does appear in the correct place.

I must be doing something wrong, or maybe misinterpreting something :) Any ideas? Maybe there's jquery/javascript out there that can monitor the page and when loading/resizing the browser, scales down that particular div?

**EDIT:** I just created a small example: http://wierdaonline.com/softest.html

In the ideal situation, the whole thing (table) should always be visible in the browser window, without any window scrollbar other than in the #content div.

Comment: Do you have a sample page to illustrate the issue?  If I'm understanding right, you have a div with 100% height and then inside that multiple divs, one of which is 100% height?  that doesn't seem to add up.

Comment: Not an example at this moment unfortunately. But you can see this as a page that has a table with 3 rows. The first has a header (one line of text), the second has a div that has height 100% with lots of content, and the third row has a one text line footer.

Basically the whole thing should be visible in the browser window at all times, so that when you resize the browser, only the 2nd row with the #content div resizes and the 1st and 3rd row remain visible. 

Like an accordeon, where the individual bags deflate when you push it into itself, except for the front and back.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to create a fixed header and footer without using tables and using fixed position:

```
#header
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
}

#middle
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#footer
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Without using tables unfortunately is not an option. My app currently is based on tables (lots of rows and tables within tables). I have tried before to get rid of all the tables, but so far have not been successful. Getting rid of the tables is a longer term project i guess. Isn't there a way to make it work with the tables and all? Great example btw @fudgey .

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow: scroll` in the div. You shouldn't need Javascript for this.

Comment: No that always shows scrollbars, while still letting the content go beyond the browser window, thus also showing the browser window scrollbar. The main (#maincontainer) content should always fit inside the browser window so if the browser is too small for displaying everything, only the #content div should have scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: these changes should work for the height, a similar thing can be done with the width if you so desire.

javascript:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var tehdiv = document.getElementById('content2');
    if($(window).height() < 100) { tehdiv.height = 50; }
    else if($(window).height() > 2000) { tehdiv.height = '100%'; }
    else { tehdiv.height = ($(window).height()/2);}
};
```

the content div's table:

```
<td valign='top' id='content2'>
```

Would something like this work?

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var minh = 50;
    var minw = 50;
    var tehh = (window.height/2);
    var tehw = (window.width/2);
    var tehdiv = document.getElementById('yourdiv');
    tehdiv.height = (tehh > minh)? tehh : minh;
    tehdiv.width = (tehw > minw)? tehw : minw;
};
```

That would make it scale to half the window size, as long as it can be bigger whan 50. You could also change the min to max and make it perform tehdiv.height = 100% at that point.

Comment: Unfortunately that function didn't do anything on my page.

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I know it's not good coding. It was not meant to be good, or even easy to read considering how small it is, just an idea of how he could do it. I'm assuming the asker knows enough js to rewrite the code, as I don't tend to write people's code for them. Feel free to fix it to your specs.

Comment: @Jeroen W Try making a fiddle and/or posting some example code. It would make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Example added to the main post.

Comment: Edited with a new version that worked in a fiddle. You might want to use $(window).height() - (however big the rest of your table is) instead of dividing by two to make the table fill the screen still.

Comment: @Truk , It's not working here :( But thank you for the replies and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The #container 100% is 100% of the page height which can be more than the window height. Setting html and body height to 100% (=100% of the window) could help, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i just tried setting html, body{ height:100%;} but that didnt make any difference.

Comment: In addition, you might have to set the table to 100% height, and then the first and last row to 1px height and the middle row to nothing for the height. This will control the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have no choice but to use tables, I modified the HTML, but actually left the CSS the same from the demo I posted in a comment above, [check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fkNuc/2/) - the only problem I've found is in IE7 where the header and footer table cell doesn't go 100% across:

CSS

```
#header, #footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
}
#footer {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="page">
    <thead>
        <tr><td id="header">Header</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td id="footer">Footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><div id="content">Content goes here</div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It's still better to [not use tables](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fkNuc/), if you get around to switching the HTML around.

Comment: Thank you for this example. It works with tables :) I have tried to implement it in my own application with many nested tables and rows, and was unsuccessful. It seems it is possible (you proved it), but just not with my setup. I may soon have another go at converting it all to a table-less setup. Not sure yet how to do it, as it failed miserably before.

Comment: Make sure you have the `thead`, `tfoot` and `tbody` in there, and that the `tfoot` is before the `tbody`... it might be better also to add the ID to the tr and not the td.

Comment: I know what you mean, but i have a load of nested tables and rows and divs mingled in between them. I can't know the exact size of every element. (like what you did with the header/footer and substract that from the content div). I could show the app, but i dont want to post the url here.